# Call WebPage without display it Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a webpage(frm_Exam.aspx) that contains a button, on-clicking of this button should call another webpage (frm_Result.aspx) .. I want to call the result page without redirecting to it .. just want to run its code (behind the Exam Page) ..

what should I do .. thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO you're doing something wrong. If you need code from a page to execute then make that code available from a class not bound to the page. Separation of concerns 101. ;)

Comment: I think this too, but this logic is performed on many stages in this project (it's not my work) so I want something not to destroy old work ..

Comment: make a class file and write your code in this class file in your case it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to to something like

```
Server.Transfer("~/NewPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute
[here for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/fb04e8f7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)